# set different title bar to collapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

i have one activity that handle on multiple list fragment with viewPager, once i clicked the item, i wish the result have a different title on the appbarr .
Here's my code, it's work for me, but i hope i can make it simple and easy to read.
would you guys help me out.

```
//set title/label activity for toolbar
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout1;
    collapsingToolbarLayout1 = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_tollbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout2;
    collapsingToolbarLayout2 = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_tollbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout3;
    collapsingToolbarLayout3 = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_tollbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout4;
    collapsingToolbarLayout4 = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_tollbar);

    //set activity title
    switch (categoryid) {
        case 1:
            collapsingToolbarLayout1.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.category_title_1) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.in_city_name));
            collapsingToolbarLayout1.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expanded_appbarr);
            collapsingToolbarLayout1.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapseAppBar);
            break;
        case 2:
            collapsingToolbarLayout2.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.category_title_2) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.in_city_name));
            collapsingToolbarLayout2.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expanded_appbarr);
            collapsingToolbarLayout2.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapseAppBar);
            break;
        case 3:
            collapsingToolbarLayout3.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.category_title_3) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.in_city_name));
            collapsingToolbarLayout3.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expanded_appbarr);
            collapsingToolbarLayout3.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapseAppBar);
            break;
        case 4:
            collapsingToolbarLayout4.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.category_title_4) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.in_city_name));
            collapsingToolbarLayout4.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expanded_appbarr);
            collapsingToolbarLayout4.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapseAppBar);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a question why are you creating multiple collapsingtoolbar layout?
Just set the title on basis of condition for same collapsing toolbar

```
collapsingToolbarLayout1.setTitle("your title")
```

and if that doesn't work then try this one

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```

If you want to set title from multiple fragments then access the activity instance in fragment and then access toolbar / collapsingToolbar, then you'll be able to set title

```
activity/getActivity().toolbar.setTitle("your title")
```